# Automatically convert POJOs to JSON with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, lombok, java-17

I would like to be able to do this:

```
System.out.printf("My obj: %s\n", myObject);
```

and have it produce JSON. So far, the best solution I have is to do this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String retVal = null;
    try {
        retVal = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException ignored) {
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

And that works, but it's annoying to do that on every single one of my POJOs. Is there an annotation I can use, or some other way to automate this. I'm using both Jackson and Project Lombok.

I tried implementing that in just the base class, but it doesn't get used for the child class. It does work if I implement it all the way down the chain.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean about not working for child classes.  you should absolutely be able to implement this in a base class and use it for hierarchies of objects extending from that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have complex inheritance classes, you should remove all of `@ToString`, `@Data` which include `@ToString` inside or any override of `toString` of the child classes.

Here is the example where all properties from child to parent are used in `toString` method:

```
My obj: {"superProperty":"super","name":"abc","number":15,"gender":true}
```

```
public abstract class BaseObject {
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String retVal = null;
    try {
      retVal = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException ignored) {
    }
    return retVal;
  }

  @Setter
  @Getter
  @AllArgsConstructor
  public static class ChildObject extends BaseObject {
    private String superProperty;
  }

  @Setter
  @Getter
  public static class ChildObject1 extends ChildObject {
    private String name;
    private int number;
    private boolean gender;

    public ChildObject1(String superProperty, String name, int number, boolean gender) {
      super(superProperty);
      this.name = name;
      this.number = number;
      this.gender = gender;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("My obj: %s\n", new ChildObject1("super","abc", 15, true));
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I had tried that, but I use project Lombok, and I'm so used to doing @Data on everything. Which generates a toString(). Switching to more specific Lombok annotations fixed the problem.